# Can I enter Malaysia on the last day of visa validity?

Tags: tourist-visas, malaysia, visa-expiration

My Malaysia visit visa issue date is 24th May 2017.
that this visa is:

> This visa is good for a single journey to Malaysia within 3 months from date hereof, provided this passport remains valid.

I have booked my tickets and arrive on 24th August 2017, but now I am not sure if I will be allowed to enter.

Comment: When are you planning to leave?

Comment: On 23rd august, arrival is on 24th

Comment: I mean when will you exit Malaysia?

Comment: 20th September..

Comment: I would suggest emailing the consulate and asking.  There are two issues here - the first is exactly how they define "3 months", the second being whether the airline will define it the same way (and thus potentially deny boarding on the grounds you don't have a valid visa).  An email response from the government/consulate will solve both of those issues.

Comment: By my common sense your visa should be valid for the duration of your stay, so you can't stay beyond August 24th, and won't be allowed in unless you can show that you'll leave the same day. But Malaysian visa terms may be different.

Answer (score 1):

No.

As you stated:

> ```
> This visa is good for a single journey to Malaysia within 3 months from date hereof, provided this passport remains valid.
> ```

Malaysian visas are issued for 90 days, and you can be in the country during that time.  Once the 90 days are up, you're expected to have left.  Any later and you're deemed to have overstayed.

So if you arrive on the last day of your visa, you could be let in, but they'll likely ask when you're leaving, as they'll note it's your last day of being allowed to be in Malaysia.  They'll see you're planning on overstaying, and then you'll run into problems.

At this point, you'll need to change travel plans, or apply for a new visa.